# Detecting detached thread calling exit(0) in google Test

Tags: c++, googletest

I need to detect my program terminating. I have a (simplified) code like this:

```
void waitForSignal()
{
   sigset_t set;
   sigemptyset(&set);
   sigaddset(&set, SIGTERM);
   pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, nullptr);

   std::thread([=] {
      int signum;
      sigwait(&set, &signum);
      exit(0);
   }).detach();
}

int main()
{
    waitForSignal();

/* Some looped code goes here */
}
```

My test case looks like this:

```
TEST(mainTest, sigKill)
{
   main();
   kill(getpid(), SIGTERM);
}
```

I have tried using Death assertions (EXPECT_EXIT) from google test but without much success, is there any way it's doable to detect exit from process in this situation using gtest?

Comment: From googletest: "Death tests use fork(), which is unsafe particularly in a threaded context". Maybe you can redesign your application not to use `exit` in the thread?